# Fetch COUNT DISTINCT data with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to get a COUNT DISTINCT data:

```
 $param = 'email';

    $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(?)) FROM contatos");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($count);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $count;
    }
```

But `echo $count` always returns 1, but i have dozens of records...

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: it's because of the DISTINCT and probably passing a unique email address.

Comment: But if i query this directly on database, works fine...

Answer (score 2):

Binding is [not allowed](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for column names (or table names). Your query is not executing correctly. You need to directly pass the name of the field.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(email)) FROM contatos");
```

Comment: It persist to return 1....:(

Comment: That's weird... Try `SELECT`ing the field `email`, instead of the `COUNT()`, and see which email it returns... and you can start from there to figure out what's wrong. Are you sure you're selecting the same database in the same host?

Comment: Yes, is the same database... I solve this alternatively: I use only `SELECT DISTINCT(email) FROM contatos`, using `$stmt->get_result()` and `echo $result->num_rows;`

Comment: Maybe you had some NULL emails... Glad you could solve it!